Pos processing in Paraview in an appropriate way with different meshes
I am writing a script to visualize the results of my calculations in ParaView. The script generates a .vtk file. I have two meshes: one defined by (Z0, Y0) and the other by (Z1, Y1). Additionally, I have an array X, which represents positions. For each value in X, there is a corresponding point in either mesh (Z0, Y0, X) or (Z1, Y1, X). The issue is that when I open the file in ParaView, there is a visible discontinuity between the meshes (Z0, Y0) and (Z1, Y1), as shown in the images. How can I adjust my script so that ParaView correctly plots the pp_abs values on this combined mesh?
neta = 61
neps = 81
ny   = neps
nz   = neta
data  = np.load('./Output/PSE3D_results_neta61_neps81_nx10_AR1.0_St0.2.npz')
X     = data['x']
Z0    = data['z'][:,0]
Y0    = data['y'][:,0]
Z1    = data['z'][:,1]
Y1    = data['y'][:,1]
Q_all = data['Q_all']
nx = len(X)
pp_real = np.zeros((neta,neps,nx),dtype=float) 
pp_imag = np.zeros((neta,neps,nx),dtype=float) 
pp_abs  = np.zeros((neta,neps,nx),dtype=float) 

for i in range(nx):
    aux = np.abs(Q_all[3*neta*neps:4*neta*neps,i])
    aux = np.transpose(np.resize(aux,(ny,nz)))
    for j in range(nz):
        for k in range(ny):
            pp_abs[j,k,i] = aux[j,k]


pp_abs/np.amax(pp_abs) 

# Example data (replace with your actual data)
nz, ny = neta, neps  # dimensions for y and z
x      = X
y, z   = np.transpose(np.resize(Y0,(ny,nz))), np.transpose(np.resize(Z0,(ny,nz)))
y1, z1 = np.transpose(np.resize(Y1,(ny,nz))), np.transpose(np.resize(Z1,(ny,nz)))
Q      = pp_abs
numb   = nx

# Open the file for writing
with open('structured_grid.vtk', 'w') as f:
    # VTK header
    f.write('# vtk DataFile Version 3.0\n')
    f.write('Structured Grid Example\n')
    f.write('ASCII\n')
    f.write('DATASET STRUCTURED_GRID\n')
    f.write(f'DIMENSIONS {numb} {ny} {nz}\n')

    # Points section
    f.write(f'POINTS {numb * ny * nz} float\n')
    for k in range(nz):
        for j in range(ny):
            for i in range(numb):
                if i < 3:
                    f.write(f'{x[i]} {y[k, j]} {z[k, j]}\n')
                else:
                    f.write(f'{x[i]} {y1[k, j]} {z1[k, j]}\n')

    # Point data section
    f.write(f'POINT_DATA {numb * ny * nz}\n')
    f.write('SCALARS Q_values float 1\n')
    f.write('LOOKUP_TABLE default\n')
    for k in range(nz):
        for j in range(ny):
            for i in range(numb):
                f.write(f'{Q[k, j, i]}\n')


Paraview is expected to make a correct connection between the two meshes
